# React Native: Update Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I was wondering how to update the flatlist after calling on my shuffle function. I have tried with the "ExtraData" tag inside the flatlist but haven´t got it to work. Any help would be appreciate!

```
    const Display = (props) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Image source={props.img} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
          <Text>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}

function Other({ navigation }) {

  function Shuffle(array){
    let x, y, z;
    for(x = 0; x<=2;x++){
      y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
      z=array[x];
      array[x] = array[y]
      array[y] = z
    } console.log(array)
  }



  let Games = [
    { title: "Tic Tac Toe", img: require("./pics/tictac.png") },
    { title: "Connect Four", img: require("./pics/ConnectFour.jpg") },
    { title: "Monopoly", img: require("./pics/mono.png") },
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList data={Games} renderItem={({ item }) => <Display source={item} title={item.title} img={item.img}> </Display>} />
      <Button title="Shuffle" onPress={() => {Shuffle(Games)}} />
    </View>
  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function isn't returning the new shuffled array and assigning it to Games. Best practice would be to store your array in useState so when it updates it forces a re-render and shows correctly.

```
const [games, setGames] = React.useState([
{ title: "Tic Tac Toe", img: require("./pics/tictac.png") },
{ title: "Connect Four", img: require("./pics/ConnectFour.jpg") },
{ title: "Monopoly", img: require("./pics/mono.png") }]);
```

Then your onPress function could call your shuffle function with Games, return the new array, then update with something like setGames(returnedArray)

Edit: Sorry just realised you also need extraData prop on FlatList to tell it to re-render. You want to have a state like 'isShuffling' which will be set as your extraData value that you toggle every time you call your shuffle function. Simplest way to do that is change between true/false as the value itself is not really important:

```
const shuffleFunc = (array) => {
//(shuffle array and return)
...

setGames(returnedArray);
setIsShuffling(prev => !prev);
```

This should prompt the FlatList to render the new order. I personally got this working by editing the flatlist-simple snack on React Native's FlatList documentation.

Comment: Still dosen´t get it to work. I get the new array in the console.log, but i wont update the Flatlist

Comment: Added the edit now :)